# Codeigniter exclude folder from path with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use codeigniter and angular together, Codeigniter mainly for backend administration of my restAPI and Angular as frontend.

Folder Structure

```
codeigniter
  -angular
  --app
  ---index.html
  -other codigniter folders
  -index.php
  -.htaccess
```

Now I would like to use my angular app but codeigniter should not interpret as controller

than I'm trying with htaccess to exclude angular folder with the following but won't work

```
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|angular)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d           
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: Im trying the same without success